# Finding conditions for a point residing in the interior of an ellipse

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have an ellipse with the equation $x^2+2y^2-2xy-1=0$. Suppose $(h,k)$ is a point residing in the interior region of the ellipse. Should this point satisfy any condition in terms of $h,k$?

Comment: You need $h^2+2k^2-2hk-1<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $\mathcal{E}$ is an ellipsoid in $\mathbb{R}^n$, defined by 
$$
\mathcal{E}\colon\mathbf{x}^T\Sigma\mathbf{x}=1,
$$
where $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Sigma\in\mathbb{S}_{++}^n$, i.e., $\Sigma$ is a positive definite matrix, then, a point $\mathbf{k}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ resides in the interior region of the ellipsoid, iff
$$
\mathbf{k}^T\Sigma\mathbf{k}<1.
$$